# Will the speed of a non-servo convey belt be affected by its load?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

By non-servo I mean that the motor has no feedback loop to maintain constant speed.

Also, may we ignore the load itself causing extra friction? Assume the belt is made of a material tense enough to not bend regardless the weight.

So, would it slow down if you put 7 tons on it compared to 1 gram?

[image: A convey belt]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would slow down.  The details would depend on the mass of the belt and the frictional forces that cause the belt to reach a constant speed without the load (when those forces match the force applied by the motor).  These frictional forces would vary with belt speed so the actual calculation might be messy.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. I was hoping for the answer to explain the laws in play and the equations involved.

Comment: Here is why it is more complicated than you expected.  Once the torque from the motor matches the frictional forces it is basically a problem of angular momentum conservation. If the belt were a simple circle with the axis at the center, it would be simple to calculate